# Expo EAS build error on Android - run gradlew step SDK 49

Tags: react-native, expo

Minimal reproducible example
When trying to build Android via eas build we get error in gradlew. after execute the follwoing command: eas build --platform android

Summary
Summary
expo SDK 49

See below the Log in EAS build:

AAR for react-native-reanimated has been found

/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/react-native-reanimated-71-hermes.aar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:buildReleasePreBundle'.

Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.

Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.

Required by:

project :app
The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.1'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-camera:

- generalReleaseRuntimeElements
- mlkitReleaseRuntimeElements

All of them match the consumer attributes:

- Variant 'generalReleaseRuntimeElements' capability Truckit.ai:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':

  - Unmatched attributes:

    - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it
    - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'generalRelease' but the consumer didn't ask for it
    - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
    - Provides attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it
- Variant 'mlkitReleaseRuntimeElements' capability Truckit.ai:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`Environment`
`Environment`
`expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:`
`System:`
`OS: macOS 12.4`
`Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash`
`Binaries:`
`Node: 20.8.1 - /usr/local/bin/node`
`npm: 10.1.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm`
`Watchman: 2023.10.09.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman`
`Managers:`
`CocoaPods: 1.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/pod`
`SDKs:`
`iOS SDK:`
`Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.5, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5`
`IDEs:`
`Xcode: 13.4.1/13F100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild`
`npmPackages:`
`@expo/webpack-config: ^19.0.0 => 19.0.0`
`expo: ^49.0.16 => 49.0.16`
`react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0`
`react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0`
`react-native: ^0.72.6 => 0.72.6`
`react-native-web: ~0.19.6 => 0.19.9`
`npmGlobalPackages:`
`eas-cli: 5.4.0`
`expo-cli: 6.3.10`
`Expo Workflow: managed`

when i try to build the app via eas build (android) we get gradle error.